# Android wear notification on top

Tags: android, notifications

I want that my notification appears on top of all existing notification stack on android wear device. I read a documentation, google says that we have to use method [setPriority()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setPriority(int))  for this notification to change notification position within notification statck. I have implemented notification like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .extend(wearableExtender)
            .setContentTitle(getSpannableTitle(flightDto.getFlightName()))
            .setContentText(getSpannableContentText(flightDto, color, status))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
```

But this code doesn't as needed, if calendar notification is on top of all, my notification appears below calendar notification.
How to show this notification on top of all notifications?

Comment: Calendar Notifications are max priority too. The system the use a set of metadata to order the notifications. You can't directly control the exact order of the notifications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To show your notification on top of all notifications except `setPriotity` you have to add **`setVibrate`** method. Here working code sample:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .extend(wearableExtender)
            .setContentTitle(getSpannableTitle(flightDto.getFlightName()))
            .setContentText(getSpannableContentText(flightDto, color, status))
            .setPriority(priority)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setOngoing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)). API doc says "Ongoing notifications are sorted above the regular notifications in the notification panel".

Comment: `setOngoing` prevents dismissing your notification using swipe from left to right and doesn't show notification on top of all. There's also one drawback system automatically add action "mute app" to your notification. If you tap this action your app will be in the "mute" state, to unmute app you should use settings in Android Wear app on your smartphone.